# ViewDidLoad is called but ViewWillAppear not called

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Basically, I've got a Collection View who's `cell.contentView` adds a ViewController's view in `willDisplayCell` of collectionView as below:

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIViewController *vc = [self.viewControllerArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   [self displayContentController:vc inView:cell];
}

- (void)displayContentController:(UIViewController *)viewController inView: (UICollectionViewCell *)cell {
   [self addChildViewController:viewController];
   viewController.view.frame = cell.bounds;
   [cell.contentView addSubview:viewController.view];
   [viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

Now, this ViewController has a tableView. In the `didSelectRowAtIndexpath` of the tableview, i'm pushing a New ViewController.

Surprisingly, the `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` of the pushed ViewController is called but the `viewWillAppear` is not called.

I also receive the following warning in the console `Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <viewController Having collection View>`

I'm not sure what wrong I am doing.

Even tried this with `cellForRowAtIndexPath` but not luck.

Answer (score 0):

The ViewController needs to be added to the `UINavigationController` stack!